# How to avoid to return an observable inside a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I'm using [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) to manage user inside my app. I'm still learning about observables and rxjs.

I'm trying to call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method - which return a promise - and to retrieve a doc from a collection.

In my service I get the document using this method:

```js
getDbUser(uid): Observable<User> {
   return this.angularFirestore.collection<User>(USERS).doc(uid).valueChanges()
}
```

and I login user with:

```js
login(user: User) {

    // sign in con email e password
    return this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then((result) => {

        if(result.user?.uid) {
        
          // get user doc
          return this.getDbUser(result.user.uid);
        }

        return null;
      });

  }
```

With this code, calling login method requires to solve a promise and then subscribe to the observable, like this:

```html
this.userService.login(this.loginUser)
  .then((userObs) => {
      userObs.subscribe((user) => {
        console.log(user);
      });
  })
```

I would really like to avoid this but I'm not sure how to to do. I tried using RxJs `toPromise` operator:

```js
login(user: User) {

    // sign in con email e password
    return this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then((result) => {

        if(result.user?.uid) {

          // recupero l'utente dal db
          return this.getDbUser(result.user.uid).toPromise();
        }

        return null;
      });

  }
```

but somehow this is not working (the promise is never resolved).

Comment: You can add `.pipe(first())` before `.toPromise`

Comment: Ok it works. Do you think it's correct to return null if the result is valid? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake writing my question. However I edited my code to throw an error when this occurs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason **toPromise()** doesn't work because the observable stays open.  Use either the **first** operator or if you're using a later version of rxjs, **firstValueFrom**.  Read more about this at [Conversion to Promises](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise) from the rxjs documentation.

Since you're using **valuesChanges** instead of **get**, then maybe your intention is to keep the observable open.  If that's the case then the best thing to do is to convert the login to an observable using **from**.

```
login(user: User) {
  return from(this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)).pipe(
    switchMap(res => (res.user.uid) 
      ? this.getDbuser(res.user.uid)
      : of(null))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first comment is the correct answer:

> You can add `.pipe(first())` before `.toPromise`"

Answer (score -1):

if you want to let know of any obserable consumer that a user just logged in only after  signInWithEmailAndPassword() has returend i would decalre a subject and subsscribe to user$ from any service consumers.

```
private userSubject$:Subject<string>=new Subject<string>();
public user$:Observable<string>=this.userSubject$.asObservable();
    login(user: User) {

    // sign in con email e password
    return this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then((result) => {

        if(result.user?.uid) {

          // recupero l'utente dal db
          return this.userSubject$.next(result.user.uid);
        }

        return null;
      });
```

}
and from outside you will use the service  :

```
this.userService.login(this.loginUser);
this.userService.user$.subscribe(user=>console.log);
```